# "The" kronecker foliation or "a" kronecker foliation?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, kt.k-theory-and-homology, noncommutative-geometry, foliations

Consider the following two foliations of torus:

1)The Kronecker foliation  with slope $\sqrt{2}$

2)The  Kronecker foliation with slope $\pi$

As I learn from the literature, these two foliations are not topological equivalent. The proof is that the K theory of their corresponding $C^{*}$ algebras are not isomorphic.In fact two Kronecker foliations with slopes $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not equivalent if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not on the same orbit of action of $Sl_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$. See Non Commutative Geometry by Alain Connes.

But **intuitively** it is difficult to imagine that these two foliations are different. because in both foliations all leaves are dense! one can not distinguish these two foliations via visible topological behavior.

> Is there an intuitive and geometric proof for this fact(without using K theory, $C^{*}$ algebras of foliation,etc.)?

I think, if there is no an intuitive proof, this shows the deep power of the role of $C^{*}$ algebra of foliations, at least in this example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just what the doctor ordered, a proof using diffeology instead of $\mathrm C^*$-algebras:

MR0799609 Donato, Paul(F-CNRS-T); Iglésias, Patrick(F-CNRS-T)
 **Exemples de groupes difféologiques: flots irrationnels sur le tore.** (French. English summary) [Examples of diffeological groups: irrational flows on the torus] 
[C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris Sér. I Math. 301 (1985), no. 4, 127–130](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5494341n/f43).

> Author summary (translated from the French): "We illustrate J.-M. Souriau's technique of `diffeological spaces and groups' in the case of the quotient $T_α$ of the standard torus by the irrational flow with slope $α$. Computing the universal covering $\mathbf R$
>    and the fundamental group $\mathbf Z^2$ of $T_α$ allows us to classify these tori diffeologically: $T_α$ and $T_β$ are diffeomorphic if and only if $α∼β$ modulo $\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbf Z)$; moreover, the computation of $\mathrm{Diff}(T_α)$ reveals a difference between quadratic irrationals and other irrationals.''

Comment: Thank you again for the interesting paper. I confess that I did not read it in details. But I review it. I think they show the foliations  are not smooth equivalent, they do not show they are not topological equivalent.Am I right?