# Classification of complex Kronecker foliations

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, foliations

Let $\theta \in \mathbb{C}$ be a fixed complex number. The submersion $f:\mathbb{C}^{2}\to \mathbb{C}\; \text{with}\;  f(x,y)=y-\theta x$ defines a complex foliation on $\mathbb{C}^{2}$. Consider the quotient foliation on each of the $\mathbb{C}^{2}/\mathbb{Z}^{2}$ or $\mathbb{C}^{2}/\mathbb{Z}^{4}$.(Here we consider the natural and obvious action of either$\mathbb{Z}^{2}$ or $\mathbb{Z}^{4}$ on $\mathbb{C}^{2})$.

> To what extend these foliations are classified up to topological equivalent(in term of $\theta$).
>
> In particular  what is the structure of this  complex foliation for real rational $\theta$? What  about irrational $\theta$?

Motivated by irrational rotation algebras, what type of $C^{*}$ algebras would appear, in this way?(The foliation $C^{*}$ algebra of this complex foliation)

Comment: Could you please describe what are those "obvious" actions ? I can think of different ones, and don't know which is the one you refer to.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier The action is  by translation. $\mathbb{Z}^{2}$ on $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ and $\mathbb{Z}^{4}$ on $\mathbb{C}^{2}\simeq \mathbb{R}^{4}$. What type of other action you are thinking about?

Comment: You have a multiplicative action $x\mapsto x\alpha$ for $\alpha\neq 0$, for instance, and the quotient is a torus if $\alpha$ is not real. Anyway, I understood that you were speaking about translation, but there still is an ambiguity, as the action of $\mathbb Z^2$ on $\mathbb C$ usually depends on a complex non-real parameter $\tau$.So I take it that $\tau=i$ here.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier I do not see the role of $\mathbb{Z}$ in the multiplicative action you mentioned. Could you please more explain? For the same reason I do not understand what was the ambiguity? The action of $\mathbb{Z}^{4}$ on $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ is $(n_{1},n_{2},n_{3},n_{4}).(x+yi,z+iw)=x+n_{1}+(y+n_{2})i, z+n_{3}+(w+n_{4})i$

Comment: Well… for $n\in\mathbb Z$ you have a diffeomorphism $x\mapsto x\alpha^n$. Similarly the additive $\mathbb Z^2$-action is given by $(n,m)\cdot x=x+n+m\tau$, which corresponds to $\tau=i$ in your example.

Comment: Anyway, the question I understand here is to describe the set of $\theta$ for which the induced foliations are topologically equivalent, right?

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier  Yes, exactly. This is already done for the real case: That is one replace $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ by $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and consider  $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$. Please see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/178073/the-kronecker-foliation-or-a-kronecker-foliation

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier  the action $x\mapsto x\alpha^{n}$ is on $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$(with quotient=torus)?

Comment: Yes, obviously you're right, the torus is the quotient of $\mathbb C^*$.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier  So it would  be interesting to find explicitly,  the foliation of $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ which quotient is the $\theta$-kronecer foliation.

Comment: The additive and multiplicative actions are related through the exponential mapping.

Comment: What do you mean by topologically equivalent? Are you calling two complex foliations (foliations of a complex manifold by complex submanifolds) equivalent if they are related by a diffemorphism, with no regard for the complex structure?

Comment: @TomGoodwillie In my question I am interested  in topological classification, So I mean  " By homeomorphism". However, maybe  it is more reasonable to compare two holomorphic foliations with holomorphic object. But I am motivated by real case which says two Kronecer foliation $\theta_{1}$ and $\theta_{2}$ are not even topological equivalent if the slops are not in the same orbit of action $Sl_{2} \mathbb{Z}:  a\theta+b/c\theta+d$

Comment: OK, but if the equivalence relation has nothing to do with complex structure then I would suggest forgetting about complex structure. Any vector subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ determines a foliation of $\mathbb R^n/\mathbb Z^n$. You could think about the case $n=3$ before the case $n=4$.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie  Prof.  Goodwillie  I really thank you very  much for your very helpful comment. I understand from your  comment that : we have a family of one dim foliations $\mathcal{F}_{\theta}, \theta \in \mathbb{R}P^{2}$ (or 2 dimensional foliation for $\theta \in G(2,3)\simeq \mathbb{R}P^{3}$). Now the question is that:"What is the topolgical classification of such foliations in term of parameter $\theta$". It would be interesting that, the action of some group(what group?) on parameter space determines this classification. Thanks again for your very interesting comment.

Comment: I correct: $G(2,3)\simeq \mathbb{R}P^{2}$.