# The diversity of Riemannian metrics adapted to a given (1 dimensional) foliation, A Krein Millman view point

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, foliations

Let $X$ be a Kronecker vector field on the two dimensional torus $\mathbb{T}^2$. Let $K$  be the space of  all 1- forms $\alpha$ of class $C^1$ on $\mathbb{T}^2$ which satisfy $d\alpha=0,\;\alpha(X)=1$.
Then $K$ is  a  convex  closed subset of  all  $C^1$  1-forms on $\mathbb{T}^2$.

> Is $K$ a compact  subset of the space of 1-forms with respect to $C^1$ topology? If  the  answer is affirmative. according to the Krein Millman theorem, what is a presise description of its  extreme points of  $K$?

> Does the topological structure of $K$ depends on chosing the vector field $X$ tangent to our initial Kronecker foliation of torus? [Does the topological structure of $K$ depend on the *slope* of our Kronecker foliation?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/178073/the-kronecker-foliation-or-a-kronecker-foliation)

**Motivation:**

A motivation for this  question is the following:

[In this post and  some  other related linked posts](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273635/finding-a-1-form-adapted-to-a-smooth-flow/273648#273648) we try to  find  a Riemannian metric compatible to orbits of  a  non vanishing vector  fields. Choosing various metrics enable us to have different  curvatuare functions. Possessing  an appropriate curvature function is very essential for appllying the Gauss Bonnet theorem to the problem of limit cycles of  vctor fields.(For counting them as closed geodesics). So this situation leads us to think about the diversity of closed differential 1-forms $\alpha$  with $\alpha(X)=1$. Under these conditions, in particular the propery of  closed convexity of this set $K$.  one is tempt  to be  curious  about the presice description of   possible extrem points of $K$.

**Remark:** For generalization of  this question to $n$ dimensional space we should consider the spaceof  all 1-form $\alpha$   with $i_X d\alpha=0,\;\alpha(X)=1$.

Comment: What is a kronecker vector field?

Comment: @ThomasRot  Vector  field $\partial_x+\alpha\partial_y$ where $\alpha$ is an irrational number. This planar vector field gives us a foliation of torus. Two  different irational $\alpha, \beta$ may introduce topologically different foliation of $\mathbb{T}^2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it is compact, but perhaps I miss a normalization condition?

Let $X=\partial_x+a\partial_y$, with $a$ irrational (doesn't actually matter for the following). Let $\alpha\in C$ (e.g. $\alpha=dx$) and let $\omega_\lambda=\lambda(a dx-dy)$, for $\lambda\in \mathbb R$. As $X$ lives in the kernel of $\omega_\lambda$, and $d\omega_\lambda=0$, then $\alpha+\omega_\lambda\in C$.

Comment: Thank you for your attention and  your very interesting answer.

Comment: But what about if we impose an upper bound on the $C^1$ norm of $\alpha$?

Comment: As you see in the motivation of the question, the only $\alpha$ I was aware in quadratic system was $d\theta$ but may be some other $\alpha$ would produce more appropriate curvature function.

Comment: This is  an example showing that the curvature associated to our proposed metric(frame)  does not work well  https://mathoverflow.net/a/278766/36688

Comment: I think you can write down differential equations for the space $B$ of $1$-forms $\beta$ satisfying $d\beta=0$ and $\beta(X)=0$. The space $C$ is $\alpha+B$. Perhaps you can find all solutions of $B$ explicitly? And then look at the unitball in $B$?

Comment: Regardless of compactness property, can one imagine some extrem points for $K$?

Comment: B is a vector space, hence K is affine. so I don’t think so